# Mysql Search for a word/sentence that has extra characteres at the end PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pattern-matching

Currently I have a query that searchs for sentences/words, it works almost as expected,

I have a regex expresion that searches for names in a table, expample:

```
function getNames($str){
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = :name 
                                    OR name REGEXP :reg1 
                                    OR name REGEXP :reg2
                                    OR name LIKE :lik1";
    $query = self::$connection->prepare($stmt);
    $query->execute(array(":name"=>$str,
                          ":reg1"=>"^$str" . "[a-zA-Z\s]*$",
                          ":reg2"=>"^[a-zA-Z]*[\s]*[$str][a-zA-Z]"  
                          ":lik1"=>"%" . $str . "%"      
    ));
   return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Let's suppose my table contains the following values

- Bob
- Peter
- Mark
- David
- John

If I run my query with `Bob` as `$name` value it gets it but I would like to be able to find `Bob` when I run the query using `BobsomeLettersExtra` or `Bob something` as `$name` value
Is there a way to do this using `REGEXP or LIKE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE  name LIKE '%".$name."%'
```

above query should be enough to get the result. You should validate data before you enter data to the table if not please use the regex as well

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%".$name."%' AND REGEXP ^".$name."[a-zA-Z]*$"
```

**UPDATE**

sorry if i have misunderstand the question please try this

```
"Select * from users  WHERE '".$name."' LIKE CONCAT(name , '%')"
```

Comment: That would work if my database table value were something like Bobbb and I would run a query like: SELECT * FROM users WHERE  name LIKE '%Bob%' that would return Bobbb but my problem is that the value in the table is Bob and the user input is Bobbb, Thanks anyway for your try

Comment: @HeribertoJuarez soory i have misunderstood the question.. check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks man, the updated answer worked very nice, Thanks a lot for your time and attention

Answer (score 0):

You may try below Query with `where` Clause for `LIKE` :

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ".$name." OR name LIKE '%".$name."%' OR name REGEXP ^".$name."[a-zA-Z]*$"
```

Comment: mmm, I tested it and nothing was found, I even tried executing the query directly from phpmyadmin (Obviously changing variables and all I needed to change)

Comment: @heriberto-juarez, I updated Query, forgot to add `OR`, you can test again, Also Can you show me your code ? If I can help you with it.

Comment: @HeribertoJuarez,How many characters you want as first characters ? for e.g. search by first 3 characters, etc... I am also searching.. tell you once i find it.,